# listview not update when action in another window

Tags: c#, wpf

My Listview is not updating where i send data in another windows, but update when send data in same windows. here is my main window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CNotes.writeLn("Jacob");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 spl = new Window1();
        spl.Show();
    }
}
```

}

and here is my window listview

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person();
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            people.Add(new Person() { Name = "John" });
            people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Jack" });

            // Data bind to the listview,
            this.lvRcvd.ItemsSource = people;
        }

        public void writeLn(string s)
        {
            this.people.Add(new Person { Name = s });
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.people.Add(new Person { Name = "Jacob" });
        }
    }

    public class Person { public string Name { get; set; } }

    static public class CNotes
    {
        static Window1 fm = new Window1();
        static public void writeLn(string s)
        {
            fm.writeLn(s);
        }

    }
```

when i click **mainwindow button1** , listview not update .
but when i click **window1 button1** , listview update

how to update listview in window1 when i click **mainwindow button1** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
static public void writeLn(string s)
    {
        fm.writeLn(s);
    }
```

To this:

```
static public void writeLn(string s)
    {
        Window1 fm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Window1>().Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
        if (fm != null)
           fm.writeLn(s);
    }
```

What you are doing is creating a new instance of form Window1 instead of accessing the open Window1 which you would like to update.

Edit:

Since this is a WPF, try using `Application.Current`. More specifically, `Application.Current.Windows`.

Comment: i use wpf , Application.Openform in winform @willy David Jr

Comment: Glad to help :)